# ValueError: inconsistent shapes after using MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, crf

I'm trying to create a Performance Evaluation Results for my CRF model, which depicts what part of speech does the word belong to. I've created a function to transform the data in a more 'datasetish' format. This function returns the data as two lists, one of Dicts of features and the other with the labels.

```py
def transform_to_dataset(tagged_sentences):
    X, y = [], []
    for sentence, tags in tagged_sentences:
        sent_word_features, sent_tags = [], []
        for index in range(len(sentence)):
            sent_word_features.append(extract_features(sentence, index)),
            sent_tags.append(tags[index])
        X.append(sent_word_features)
        y.append(sent_tags)
    return X, y
```

then I divide the set BEFORE encoding to have full sentences in training/testing sets.

```
penn_train_size = int(0.8*len(penn_treebank))
penn_training = penn_treebank[:penn_train_size]
penn_testing = penn_treebank[penn_train_size:]
X_penn_train, y_penn_train = transform_to_dataset(penn_training)
X_penn_test, y_penn_test = transform_to_dataset(penn_testing)
```

and then I load the model for it to train and test my data

```
penn_crf = CRF(
    algorithm='lbfgs',
    c1=0.01,
    c2=0.1,
    max_iterations=100,
    all_possible_transitions=True
)
#The fit method is the default name used by Machine Learning algorithms to start training.
print("Started training on Penn Treebank corpus!")
penn_crf.fit(X_penn_train, y_penn_train)
print("Finished training on Penn Treebank corpus!")
```

and then I test it with

```
y_penn_pred=penn_crf.predict(X_penn_test)
```

But when I try

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_penn_test, y_penn_pred))
```

It gives off an error:

> ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data
> representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a
> binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer
> transformer can convert to this format.

But when I try to use MultiLabelBinarizer;

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

bin_y_penn_test = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y_penn_test)
bin_y_penn_pred = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y_penn_pred)
```

It gives me an error of:

> ValueError: inconsistent shapes

Here's the full traceback

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
> /tmp/ipykernel_5694/856179584.py in 
> 1 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
> 2
> ----> 3 print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(bin_y_penn_test, bin_y_penn_pred))
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
> inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
> 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
> 62             if extra_args <= 0:
> ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
> 64
> 65             # extra_args > 0
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py
> in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
> 203     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
> 204     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):
> --> 205         differing_labels = count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)
> 206         score = differing_labels == 0
> 207     else:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in
> **sub**(self, other)
> 431         elif isspmatrix(other):
> 432             if other.shape != self.shape:
> --> 433                 raise ValueError("inconsistent shapes")
> 434             return self._sub_sparse(other)
> 435         elif isdense(other):
>
> ValueError: inconsistent shapes

What should I do so that I could produce the confusion matrix of my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
penn_train_size = int(0.7*len(penn_treebank))
```

Then check if the shape is still inconsistent

```
bin_y_penn_test.shape
bin_y_penn_pred.shape
if bin_y_penn_test.shape == bin_y_penn_pred.shape:
    print('Consistent Shape')
else:
    print('Inconsistent Shape')
```

If it gives off consistent shape, do

```
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
multilabel_confusion_matrix(bin_y_penn_test, bin_y_penn_pred)
```

However if it still isn't consistent, try to tinker on your data.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Why is it that when I do *0.8 it yields an inconsistent shape?